# Exclude specific module files in py2app

Tags: python, matplotlib, py2app

I am creating an app and I'm using py2app so I can create a package I can distribute.  Because I will be distributing my app as a download, I am trying to get its size down.

My app uses matplotlib, a rather large module.  I noticed that py2app included a `tests` folder from matplotlib that is very large (48.7 MB).  I was wondering if there was a way to tell py2app to exclude this particular file instead of me having to manually delete it from the app's contents (The app still works fine if I remove it that way).

I know py2app has an `excludes` parameter, but nothing I try seems to remove files from within the module (I've even tried a full file path).  Is there a way to tell py2app to remove files like this? Also, am I fine with just manually deleting the file like I did?

Here is the file path I'm trying to remove:
`AppName/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.4/matplotlib/tests`

I am using Python 3.4